# Add Custom Post Type to Current Query

Tags: custom-post-types, query, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to create a plugin which adds a new custom post type and it should be shown at the same locations as a normal post (front page, archives etc.).

**Is there any functions for me to retrieve the post types which are currently being called in the query so that I can modify and add my CPT to the current query? (example stated in 2nd comment if my question sounds confusing)**

I can't use the code below (i.e. list the post types) because I can't predict what post types would the user have :

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'album', 'movie', 'quote' ) );

return $query;
}
```

Similarly, I can't use the code below because that would return **all** post types, including those which might not be intended to be shown at the front page :

```
if ( !is_admin() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ) );

    if ($post_type) {
        $post_type = $post_type;
    } else {
        $post_type = $post_types;
    }

    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```

So, is there any ideas how I can add my CPT to the query without affecting other post types? Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the situation or I'm not understanding you. You have said: " ... to retrieve the post types which are currently being called in the query so that I can add this CPT to the query ...". If they are currently called in the query .... why you want to include them again??? Please, explain better the situation and the problem.

Comment: For example, that query might be retrieving content from 'post' and 'page'. I would like those to remain but add my CPT to it, such that it's now getting content from 'post', 'page' and 'my-CPT'. Both the approaches above can't seem to work this way, with the second approach also including other post types. Does this make things clearer?

Comment: No, it is not clear. You said "retrieve the post types which are currently being called in the query" but it seems that they are not included and you want to include them. I don't understand why the code in your answer doesn't work. **It seems that you want to include custom post types but you don't know what custom post types to include**. Am I right? If you don't know what custom post types want to include, how do you expect we can know it? You will have to describe the situation more deeply. Fore example, where the CPT come from, how they are selected to be included and so on.

Comment: Well, it's a plugin which will be used by others who might have other CPTs being used concurrently, so I can't hard-code the post types to be retrieved (i.e. first approach won't work in this case). The code above will only work if I know all the post types required. I thought maybe there's a way to get all the post types in the current query and add my CPT to the array. Hence, in situations like this, what would be the best way to make my CPT show *along with* contents from other post types? @David's understanding of my question is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually not that far away with `pre_get_posts`, you just need to first grab the current post types that are in the query before adding your own.

Also, I'd recommend using a `$priority` of `99` so that the action is hooked after any other `pre_get_posts` hooks, meaning that if users add there own CPT's (or built in post types) they are detected and included by the function below (but you can change that as required).

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'djg_includ_my_cpt_in_query', 99);
function djg_includ_my_cpt_in_query($query){

    if(is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) :              // Ensure you only alter your desired query

        $post_types = $query->get('post_type');             // Get the currnet post types in the query

        if(!is_array($post_types) && !empty($post_types))   // Check that the current posts types are stored as an array
            $post_types = explode(',', $post_types);

        if(empty($post_types))                              // If there are no post types defined, be sure to include posts so that they are not ignored
            $post_types[] = 'post';         
        $post_types[] = 'document';                         // Add your custom post type

        $post_types = array_map('trim', $post_types);       // Trim every element, just in case
        $post_types = array_filter($post_types);            // Remove any empty elements, just in case

        $query->set('post_type', $post_types);              // Add the updated list of post types to your query

    endif; 

    return $query;

}
```

## EDIT

When constructing the final query, WordPress checks to see if 'post_type' is empty, and if so the following code is executed -

```
$where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'";
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object ( 'post' );
```

So what happens when we add a CPT is that WordPress assuems we want to ignore posts as it is not explicitly declared.  That is were my scenario differed - I had explicitly declared other post types previously so they were included in the call `$post_types = $query->get('post_type');`.

So, in your case we can resonably summise that if `$post_types` is empty, the user does not wish to amend that portion of the query so 'post' can be manually added to the `$post_types` array.  This should (hopefully!) do the trick.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't know what custom post types should added to `$post_types[]`. That is the question asked.

Comment: Note that the OP said "I can't predict what post types would the user have"

Comment: @cybmeta - The OP wants to amend the query my keeping the post types that would be queried, but by also adding the `CPT` as generated by his plugin.  Therefore you must get the post types currently in the query (`$post_types = $query->get('post_type');`), add the new CPT (`$post_types[] = 'document';`), and then update the query (`$query->set('post_type', $post_types);`).

Comment: @cybmeta - Exactly, the user said `"I can't predict what post types would the user have"`, therefore before adding the CPT you need to work out what post types are currently in `$query`. The users question of `how I can add my CPT to the query without affecting other post types?` also seems pretty clear in this regard.

Comment: I understood that the OP can not have a list of CPT to add to current query, so filling `$post_types[]` with hardcoded custom post types as you suggested is not possible. Maybe I didn't understood the question???.

Comment: @cymetat - The user is creating a new CPT, that is the only CPT that he wishes to append (as far as I understand the question).  The only other requirement was to keep the post types currently in `$query`, so it doesn't matter what other post types or CPT's have been added by users using the plugin as using `$query->get('post_type')` will ensure that they are preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didn't work when I tried it just now (tried it at index.php, only the CPT content was retrieved, content from 'post' wasn't retrieved). Is there a problem with `$post_types = $query->get('post_type'); `? I didn't downvote it though, it sounds logical to me but somehow didn't work as expected.

Comment: @Billy - if this is going to be included in a plugin, then `index.php` is the wrong place to put it; place it within your plugin file.  As for it not working - have you removed the code you entered in your question?  If so, could there be any other `pre_get_posts` hooks affecting the query?  The code in my answer is actually an example from one of my sites (although I added notes and changed the function name), and it works perfectly :)

Comment: Ahh, I see why it's not working for you... It's a very slightly different scenario. I'll see if I can find a work around, please bare with me...

Comment: @David - Sorry for the confusion, I mean, I tested it at index.php (default front page showing latest posts) with the code in the plugin file. I'm using Twenty Fifteen to test and other plugins have been disabled, so there shouldn't be other conflicts. I think `$post_types = $query->get('post_type');` is empty. Edit : Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  I've now updated my answer to (hopefully) fit your scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem! Also, Merry Christmas :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)